# I get an error during user login in my codeigniter project

Tags: codeigniter-3

I get an error during user login in my codeigniter project. Codes are running smoothly in a different project. However, I am getting errors in my own project.

Error is:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property 'fskara' of non-object

Filename: controllers/Auth.php

Line Number: 16

Backtrace:

File: /home/directory/application/controllers/Auth.php
Line: 16
Function: _error_handler
```

My Auth controllers file

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Auth extends CI_Controller {
  public function index()
  {
    $this->load->view('admin/giris');
  }

  public function loginto()
  {
    $kadi = $this->input->post('kadi');
    $sifre = $this->input->post('sifre');

    $this->load->model('vt');
    $sonuc = $this->vt->single('yonetici',array('ykullanici'->$kadi,'ysifre'->$sifre));
    print_r($sonuc);
  }
}
```

My VT Model file

```
<?php

class Vt extends CI_Model
{
    function single($from,$where=array())
    {
      $sonuclar=$this->db
      ->from($from)
      ->where($where)
      ->get()
      ->row();
      return $sonuclar;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assoc array is wrong. Change `->` to `=>`

```
$sonuc = $this->vt->single('yonetici',array('ykullanici'=>$kadi,'ysifre'=>$sifre));
```

Other than that i can't find `fskara` anywhere in your code.

Comment: fskara is username. I try your solution.